# ldapmodify olcTLSCipherSuite truncates ciphers recommended by Red Hat

Tags: centos7, openldap, slapd

I am trying to modify our SSL Ciphers for slapd using ldapmodify on CentOS7.

openldap-2.4.44-25 is used.

The ciphers I am using are the ones recommended by Red Hat for RHEL7: [Strongest available ciphers only](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1474813#:%7E:text=Strongest%20available%20ciphers%20only)

```
olcTLSCipherSuite: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:!RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!EDH:!EXP:!SSLV2:!eNULL
```

My ldif file looks like this:

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcTLSCipherSuite
olcTLSCipherSuite: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:!RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!EDH:!EXP:!SSLV2:!eNULL
```

The command I am running locally is:
`ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f ciphers.ldif`

What I get is a truncated line:

```
olcTLSCipherSuite: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:AES256-HA256:!RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNU$
  LL:!EDH:!EXP:!SSLV2:!eNULL$
```

The dollar at the end of each line is just the EOL enabled in vim to show that ldapmodify creates an EOL in the middle of the string.

What am I missing?

I tried to use quotes around the string but it did not help.

Using this string also truncates the attribute:

```
olcTLSCipherSuite: EECDH:EDH:CAMELLIA:ECDH:RSA:!eNULL:!SSLv2:!RC4:!DES:!EXP:!SEED:!IDEA:!3DES
```

However, using a shorter one works as expected:

```
olcTLSCipherSuite:  ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
```

Comment: There seem to be a limitation on the ldif attributes set to 76 characters.
This was already raised in 2003: https://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-devel/200305/msg00049.html

In the end I am using this:
`olcTLSCipherSuite: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:!RC4:HIGH`

Along with `olcTLSProtocolMin: 3.3` I am where we wanted to be.